# SQLite Android Leaked

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-leaks

I've this method to read the database:

class BDUtilities

```
    private Context context;
    private BDHelper bd;
    private SQLiteDatabase db_reader;
    private SQLiteDatabase db_writer;


    public BDUtilities(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.bd = new BDHelper(context);
        this.db_reader = bd.getReadableDatabase();
        this.db_writer = bd.getWritableDatabase();
    }

     public ArrayList<Boolean> getPreferences() {
        ArrayList<Boolean> resultados = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        if (checkBeforeUse()) {
            try {
                int user_id = getUserId();

                Cursor c = db_reader.rawQuery("select cb_save_login, cb_save_pic_after_share," +
                        "cb_upload_anonym, cb_init_cat_pref, user_id from prefs where user_id = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(user_id) });

                if (c.getCount() > 0){
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_save_login"))));
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_save_pic_after_share"))));
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_upload_anonym"))));
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_init_cat_pref"))));
                    c.close();
                } else { c.close(); }
            }
            finally {
                //both error
                //bd.close();
                //db_reader.close(); //error:
                //01-12 06:05:36.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1681): java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
                //attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:                   
                //data/data/com.example.photopt/databases/projeto_ddm.db
            }
        }
        return resultados;
     }
```

I've tried to close **db_reader** that has **bd_reader = database.getReadableDatabase();** but has error.

This code:
This doesn't return error but after some uses it shows this:

> 01-12 05:51:29.647: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(1762): A SQLiteConnection
>   object for database
>   '/data/data/com.example.photopt/databases/projeto_ddm.db' was leaked! 
>   Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly
>   and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Comment: What error does this throw: `db_reader.close()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307868/a-sqliteconnection-object-for-database-was-leaked-please-fix-your-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190218/android-sqliteconnection-object-for-database-was-leaked-even-closed

Comment: i've seen that didn't worked, error is displayed above

Comment: Do you close the `db_reader` only or `bd` too when "already closed" error is thrown?

Comment: You need to change this code if (c.getCount() > 0){
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_save_login"))));
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_save_pic_after_share"))));
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_upload_anonym"))));
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_init_cat_pref"))));
                    c.close();
                } else { c.close(); }

Comment: Close your cursor... cursor.close();  in your case. c.close();

Comment: @DirkDeWinnaar I close it, you can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not closing `db_writer`

Regardless of not using it, you still open it at the intialisation.

```
    this.db_writer = bd.getWritableDatabase();
```

It is recommended to close it also, else the connection is leaked.

```
   this.db_writer.close();
```

Better yet would be to write a helper method that you can call:

```
public void CloseDb()
{
    if(db_writer.isOpen())
        db_writer.close();
    if(db_reader.isOpen())
        db_reader.close();

}
```

You can then call `CloseDb()` where appropriate (still need to close cursors as per normal).
This method checks its open before closing, so does not try to close it twice.

You do not normally close a `Databasehelper` from within itself though. Usually once you have finished using it in an from an `activity`. (Call `CloseDb()` from your activity once you have finished, aka, `onPause` or `onDestroy`.)

Comment: Could you please help to solve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646206/unable-to-prevent-sqliteconnection-object-leakage)

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
if (c.getCount() > 0){
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_save_login"))));
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_save_pic_after_share"))));
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_upload_anonym"))));
                    resultados.add(parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cb_init_cat_pref"))));
                    c.close();
                    bd.close();
                } else {
                  c.close(); 
                  bd.close();
                }
```

Comment: isn't this the same to have finally { bd.close(); } ??

Answer (score 0):

this code stops the leak and fixes cursor problems.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

  private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
  private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table_name";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    // Use the application context, which will ensure that you 
    // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
    if (sInstance == null) {
      sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
  }

  /**
   * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
   * make call to static factory method "getInstance()" instead.
   */
  private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
}
```